# Pattern matching with string containing dots

Tags: java, regex

Pattern is:

```
private static Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(.*\\..*\\..*)\\..*");
```

String is:

```
    sentVersion = "1.1.38.24.7";
```

I do:

```
    Matcher m = r.matcher(sentVersion);
    if (m.find()) {
        guessedClientVersion = m.group(1);
    }
```

I expect 1.1.38 but the pattern match fails. If I change to `Pattern.compile("(.*\\..*\\..*)\\.*");`

> // notice I remove the "." before the last *

then `1.1.38.XXX` fails

My goal is to find (x.x.x) in any incoming string.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is probably due to greedy-ness of your regex. Try this negation based regex pattern:

```
private static Pattern r = Pattern.compile("([^.]*\\.[^.]*\\.[^.]*)\\..*");
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/sJ5rD4

Answer (score 2):

Make your `.*` matches [reluctant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with `?`

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(.*?\\..*?\\..*?)\\..*");
```

otherwise `.*` matches the whole `String` value.

#### See here: http://regex101.com/r/lM2lD5